# Handling duplicate insertion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

So I've got this piece of code which, logically should work but Entity Framework is behaving unexpectedly.

Here:

```
foreach (SomeClass someobject in allObjects)
{
    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();

    supplier.primary_key = someobject.id;
    supplier.name = someobject.displayname;

    try
    {
       sm.Add(supplier);
       ro.Created++;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ro.Error++;
    }
}
```

Here's what I have in sm.Add()

```
    public Supplier Add(Supplier supplier)
    {
        try
        {
            _ctx.AddToSupplier(supplier);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
             return supplier;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I can have records in **allObjects** that have the same id. My piece of code needs to support this and just move on to the next and try to insert it, which I think should work.

If this happens, an exception is throw, saying that records with dupe PKs cannot be inserted (of course). The exception mentions the value of the PK, for example **1000**.

All is well, a new **supplier** is passed to **sm.Add()** containing a PK that's never been used before. (**1001**)

Weirdly though, when doing SaveChanges(), EF will whine about not being able to insert records with dupe PKs. The exception still mentions **1000** even though **supplier** contains **1001** in **primary_key**.

I feel this is me not using **_ctx** properly. Do I need to call something else to sync it ?

Comment: What is the structure of the Database fields ..? and why do all your records share the same ID.. there is definitely something incorrectly you are doing.. can you provide a schema of the table(s) layout..?

Comment: Where do you see I'm using the same ID ? It's a foreach loop containing objects and sometimes, some of them can have the same .id value which ends up being passed in supplier.primary_key. Not ALL of the records use the same ID.

Comment: I was asking this because you have written this "I can have records in allObjects that have the same id. My piece of code needs to support this and just move on to the next and try to insert it, which I think should work."

Comment: Regardless, I need to be able to move on and insert other records that do not have a duplicate PK. But my context is remembering the previous PK that errored out when moving on to the next...

Comment: take a look at this posting and refactor the way that you are doing your Inserts using Entity.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, had to change something in the Add() method:

```
public Supplier Add(Supplier supplier)
{
    try
    {
        _ctx.AddToSupplier(supplier);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
         return supplier;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ctx.Supplier.Detach(supplier);
        throw;
    }
}
```